# How to view LDAP entries using web console?

Tags: ldap, ibm-directory-server

I am new to LDAP and using 'Security Directory Server'

I have added entries via LDIF file successfully

> ./ldapadd -h ldap://localhost:389 -D "cn=root" -w root  -f
>   /tmp/example.ldif

How to view the entries using 'Web Console' that were added ?

I restarted both 'server instance' and 'administration server'

I logged onto 'http://localhost:12100/IDSWebApp/IDSjsp/Logout.jsp' but I could not find any link other than 'Console Administration'

Answer (score 0):

After you login to the IBM Directory Server Web Administration tool you need to use the (default) username *superadmin* and password *secret*. After that you need to add the LDAP server you want to manage under *Manage console servers*.

Steps to accomplish this are documented in the IBM Knowledge Center under [Starting the Web Administration Tool](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVJJU_6.3.0/com.ibm.IBMDS.doc/install179.htm%23startwa).

In the fifth and last step in the documentation linked above you use the same web interface to logon and administrate your LDAP instance:

> Log in as the directory server instance administrator:
>   On the IBM Tivoli Directory Server Web Administration Login Tool page, select the LDAP host name or IP address for your computer from the drop-down menu for the LDAP Hostname field.
>   Type the administrator DN and the password for the directory server instance. You specified these fields during instance creation.
>   Click Login on the lower left side of the window.

Comment: I logged on using default user Id and pwd and added the 'ldap server' manually.  Logged out and logged on but still I was not able to view the realms / suffixes which I added